# node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.18.3 (node-v72 ABI, unknown)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, web-deployment

I cloned a `MERN` boilerplate from GitHub but when I executed `npm install`, this error appeared. Hope someone can help me.

```sh
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.18.3 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Remote end closed socket abruptly.
```

Comment: Kind post the entire error returned, and the `package.json`, thanks.

Comment: the error message is long. see the [link](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3j8j) for the message. Then [here](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3j8k) is the package.json